# Create Database from AWS CLI without providing a password

Tags: amazon-rds, aws-cli

is there an elegant way to create a RDS instance without providing the credentials in plain text?

I already created a secret, but I can't find any documentation about how to use a secret when creating a database.

My current solution is saving the password in a file and reading it into a variable:

```
$ vim password.txt
$ pw=$(cat password.txt)
$ aws rds create-db-instance \
  # all the arguments \
  --master-user-password $pw
```

Update: I figured another way:

```
$ read -s -p "enter password: " pw 
$ aws rds ... --master-user-password $pw
```

Answer (score 0):

openejb-core jar is a library that can be used to cipher and decipher text. You can use this library to cipher the actual password and store the ciphered password in the text file 'password.txt'.
While retrieving the password into 'pw' variable, you can decipher it again and use it further. Hence, the actual password is never visible, even with root access.